# Automapper error System.ArgumentException mapping subentities

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Im sorry my language primary is not English. I have classes I mapped using AutoMapper that was working before but stopped working and now show error exception **`System.ArgumentException: 'Property 'System.String OtherSubName' is not defined for type`**

```
public class EntityFrom
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SubEntityFrom SubEntityFrom { get; set; }
}

public class SubEntityFrom
{
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public OtherSubEntityFrom OtherSubEntityFrom { get; set; }
}

public class OtherSubEntityFrom
{
    public string OtherSubName { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTarget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public string OtherSubName { get; set; }
}
```

I configure the mapping like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<OtherSubEntityFrom, EntityTarget>();

cfg.CreateMap<SubEntityFrom, EntityTarget>()
    .IncludeMembers(x => x.OtherSubEntityFrom);

cfg.CreateMap<EntityFrom, EntityTarget>()
    .IncludeMembers(x => x.SubEntityFrom);
```

Comment: Upgrade AutoMapper!

Comment: which version of AutoMapper are you using? try to update AutoMapper to it's latest versin

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Is this a known bug that was fixed? Could you give me a link to the issue or pullrequest the fixed it?

Comment: @styx I'm using version AutoMapper 10.0.0